# How do you share access to a resource in java without synchronizing the code?

Tags: java, concurrency

I got asked the following question in an interview while talking about concurrency in Java. I couldnt come up with a good strategy. Any ideas?

How do you share access to a resource in java without synchronizing the code?

Comment: Restrict all access to read-only?  Copy the resource per subscriber?  Use an atomic reference to emulate synchronization?

Comment: I think elaborating on what your situation looks like, and what you want to achieve will ultimately help you get better/more helpful answers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the resource is immutable then no synchronization is needed, but barring that, here are a few ideas:

1. **Restrict all access to read-only**: if nothing is updating the resource then any number of concurrent threads can safely have read access to it.
2. **Copy the resource per subscriber**: any number of threads can have their own copy of a resource and safely modify it with no impact on other threads with their own copy.  (e.g. [`ThreadLocal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html))
3. **Use an atomic reference to emulate synchronization**: a "getter" method use check an atomic reference (e.g. [`AtomicBoolean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html)) to create a "check in" / "check out" system to ensure that only one thread has access to the resource, no synchronization needed.
4. **Use a lock from [`java.util.concurrent.locks`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html)**: which can provide the same (or even better) functionality without using the `synchronized` keyword.

Of course, the interviewer might impose additional restrictions but these are good starting points given the little information in your question.

Answer (score 2):

make the resource IMMUTABLE: here is the official java tutorial from Oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the situation if it's possible but what comes to my mind:
Make the shared resource immutable or make the shared resource stateless

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Lock object. Check this one for example: [ReentrantReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html)

Answer (score 0):

If using volatile keyword is not considered "synchronizing the code" then it might help in some situation.  And how about using collection classes that are synchronized already like ConcurrentHashMap or Vector?